# How to pass data between two ViewController using closure

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, closures

I want to know how to pass data using closure. I know that there are three types of data pass approaches:

- delegate
- Notification Center
- closure

I want proper clarification of closure with an example.

Comment: What have you already tried? Provide some code. It's not code writing community. Thanks

Comment: though I have provided you sample below, but you should not ask for code. Rather you should try and any confusion /problems should be sorted out here!

Comment: I do think this question is invalid. for syntax you can visit the documentation page. blocks documentation is here: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ios/6888/block#t=201706140953118422187

Comment: Agree with @Joshua, Though I provided code for what is needed, I also think this is not a platform for sharing exact code, for that Apple provides detailed documentation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well passing data with blocks / closures is a good and reasonable approach and much better than notifications.
Below is the same code for it.

**First ViewController (where you make object of Second ViewController)**

```
 @IBAction func push(sender: UIButton) {
        let v2Obj = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("v2ViewController") as! v2ViewController
        
        v2Obj.completionBlock = {[weak self] dataReturned in
            //Data is returned **Do anything with it **
            print(dataReturned)
        }
        navigationController?.pushViewController(v2Obj, animated: true)
        
    }
```

**Second ViewController (where data is passed back to First VC)**

```
import UIKit
typealias v2CB = (infoToReturn :String) ->()
class v2ViewController: UIViewController {
        var completionBlock:v2CB?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func returnFirstValue(sender: UIButton) {
        guard let cb = completionBlock else {return}
        cb(infoToReturn: "any value")
    }
    
}
```

Comment: "completionBlock = {(dataReturned) -> ()in"   what is this ??

Comment: its where you got data back in variable dataReturned

Comment: can u explain me with pass any Actual data ?

Comment: in second VC, using -> cb(infoToReturn: returnFirstValue) data is passed back to first VC.

Comment: **Thanks Ankit**

Comment: wc bro !! mind accepting if any of the answers helped you!

Comment: Hello Ankit, guard let cb = completionBlock else {return} it gives me nil please help me !! I'm doing same thing that you write in code Thank You :)

Comment: @YogeshPatel, this happens when you don't set completionBlock:
v2Obj.completionBlock = {(dataReturned) -> ()in }

Comment: But it gives me error in V2ViewController returnFirstValue Function

Comment: guard let cb = completionBlock else {return}  cb is nil in my case

Comment: Its still confusing shouldn't in  cb(infoToReturn: returnFirstValue) the returnFirstValue needs to be a string here like "Test" or some data, how can you pass a function name

Answer (score 0):

This example explains use of service call with Alamofire and send the response back to calling View Controller with closure.

**Code in Service Wrapper Class:**

***Closure declaration***

```
typealias CompletionHandler = (_ response: NSDictionary?, _ statusCode: Int?, _ error: NSError?) -> Void
```

***Closure implementation in method***

```
    func doRequestFor(_ url : String, method: HTTPMethod, dicsParams : [String: Any]?, dicsHeaders : [String: String]?, completionHandler:@escaping CompletionHandler) {

        if !NetworkReachablity().isNetwork() {
            return
        }

        if (dicsParams != nil) {print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>Request info url: \(url) --: \(dicsParams!)")}
        else {print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>Request info url: \(url)")}

        Alamofire.request(url, method: method, parameters: dicsParams, encoding:
            URLEncoding.default, headers: dicsHeaders)

        .responseJSON { response in
            self.handleResponse(response: response, completionHandler: completionHandler)
        }
    }
```

**Code at calling view controller:**

```
        ServiceWrapper().doRequestFor(url, method: .post, dicsParams: param, dicsHeaders: nil) { (dictResponse, statusCode, error) in

        }
```

Comment: Brother read My Question again. and i want to pass local data Not from JSON data format

Comment: what is wrong brother? In the example I have posted, Service Wraper class passes data to calling viewcontroller using closure. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Sagarvaishnav, there is no sign of local data in your question, moreover you can pass whatever data you want, what I posted is just an example, not exact dode you need. Thanks.