# Callback function not reloading database

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have an application where I get store and retrieve data from realm. I created a popUp that contains a textfield for input of the data and I also created a callback function that I use to reload the tableview after the save button is clicked but the problem now is the table does not get reloaded when the button is clicked.

**AddCategory.swift**

```
 //Callback:- Property that holds a function
var doneSaving: (() -> ())?

@IBAction func saveActionBtn(_ sender: Any) {

        CategoryFunctions.instance.createCategory(name: name, color: color, isCompleted: false)

        if let doneSaving = doneSaving {
            doneSaving()
        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

**category.swift**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if (segue.identifier == Constants.TO_ADD_CATEGORY_VC) {

            let popUp = segue.destination as! AddCategoryVC
            //2 Callback implemented
            popUp.doneSaving = {[weak self] in
                self?.tableView.reloadData()
            }

        }
    }
```

am I doing anything wrong or what can I do to fix this?

```
func createCategory(name: String, color: String, isCompleted: Bool) -> Void {

        let category = CategoryModel()
        category.name = name
        category.color = color
        category.isCompleted = false
        DBManager.instance.addData(object: category)

    }

//MARK:- Read Category
    func readCategory(completion: @escaping CompletionHandler) -> Void {


                DBManager.instance.getDataFromDB().forEach({ (category) in
                    let category = CategoryModel()
                    Data.categoryModels.append(category)

                })

    }


func getDataFromDB() -> Results<CategoryModel> {
        let categoryArray: Results<CategoryModel> = database.objects(CategoryModel.self)
        return categoryArray
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Constants.CATEGORY_CELL) as! CategoryCell
        let category = categoryArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.setup(categoryModel: category)
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Is the closure called at all? By the way this is Swift, there is optional chaining: Just write `doneSaving?()` and delete the `if let` wrapper.

Comment: should I make it non optional? @Sh_Khan

Comment: @vadian the closure is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since from here

[Crashing on writing to realm database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52018505/crashing-on-writing-to-realm-database/52018632#52018632)

you only save the data to realm you need to reload it before  reloading the table

```
popUp.doneSaving = {[weak self] in

 self?.tableView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return categoryArray.count
    }
```

Comment: That does not reload the tableview too

Comment: sure that prepareForSegue is called , do you use peformSegue ??

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44540818/how-to-pass-data-between-two-viewcontroller-using-closure

Comment: Add print statement inside [weak self] to assure it's being called ??

Comment: it is called just confirmed with a print statement

Comment: Added this line **categoryArray = DBManager.instance.getDataFromDB()** ?? also i suppose from other posts that the dataSource of the table is **categoryArray** ??

Comment: share what inside **CategoryFunctions.instance.createCategory** and **DBManager.instance.getDataFromDB()** with what inside **cellForRowAt**

Comment: can you scroll to see the added item , or it's not being shown at all ??

Comment: i have to reload the application to view every newly added  items

Comment: the tableview is supposed to reload automatically on Save button clicked

Comment: ok print the count before and after addition to verify that , also add print inside cellForRowAt to verify it's called when you reload

Comment: it does not get printed in the donSaving but does in the cellForRowAt  `print("COUNT IS \(categoryArray.count)")`

Comment: or do you have any alternatives to my method?

Comment: I resolved it. The problem was my numberOfRowsInSection

Comment: Thank you for your contribution